# Error on Firebase Transaction: [Error: Set]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to increment the value of "view_amount" from my node app in the background, but it only seems to work half the time when there's a big load on it. The other half, I get this error:

```
[Error: set]
```

This is my code (Coffeescript):

```
@ref.firebaseClient.child('listings').child(val.listing_id).child("view_amount").transaction (current_value) ->
  (current_value || 0) + 1
, (error, committed, snapshot) ->
  if error
    console.log error
```

And this is the path I'm setting it on:

```
{
  "headline" : "Yeezy Boost 750",
  "shoe_size" : 9.5,
  "short_url" : "K5wv",
  "size_type" : "men",
  "status" : "active",
  "style_code" : "BB1840",
  "timestamp" : 1467842400000,
  "view_amount" : 3043,
  "watching_amount" : 2
}
```

What could make the transaction code fail? Is it possible I'm running a transaction too many times a second on that specific path? Does the transaction fail if I change the "style_code" at the same time as running the transaction?

Update: This is the error I'm getting on my Node worker. I find the "set" error quite confusing, since I'm trying to do a transaction on the path "view_amount". I'm at no point doing a "set" on that path.

```
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:  error:    Error: set 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at Error (native) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at hi (/app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:222:395) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at Yh (/app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:220:351) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at /app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:220:286 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at /app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:145:167 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at Dg.h.ud (/app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:146:104) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at rg.ud (/app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:137:364) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at Xf.eg (/app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:135:280) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at $f (/app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:123:109) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].Ka.onmessage (/app/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:121:467) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].EventTarget.dispatchEvent (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api/event_target.js:22:30) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].instance._receiveMessage (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api.js:134:10) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api.js:34:49) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at emitOne (events.js:82:20) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].emit (events.js:169:7) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:451:14) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at pipe (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js:37:40) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].Pipeline._loop (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js:44:3) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].Pipeline.processIncomingMessage (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/pipeline/index.js:13:8) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].instance.processIncomingMessage (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/node_modules/websocket-extensions/lib/websocket_extensions.js:133:20) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].instance._emitMessage (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:442:22) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].instance._emitFrame (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:405:19) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].instance.parse (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/hybi.js:141:18) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].instance.parse (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/driver/client.js:62:58) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at [object Object].IO.write (/app/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/faye-websocket/node_modules/websocket-driver/lib/websocket/streams.js:80:16) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:528:20) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at emitOne (events.js:77:13) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10) 
Aug 17 12:15:44 Worker app/worker.1:    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the poor error message, but this error means that you did a `set()` or `update()` operation on a related path (anything at, above, or below `/listings/<val.listing_id>/view_amount`) before the transaction completed, and so we cancelled the transaction since we don't know if we should re-run the transaction on top of your `set()` or if your `set()` should override the transaction's write, etc.

In general, you need to be careful not to mix `set()` and `transaction()` calls on the same part of your database.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen Ok... so just to clarify. If I set "watching_amount" the same time I run the transaction on "view_amount", there's a good chance that the transaction won't go through? What if I update the "watching_amount" instead of setting it. Is there any difference between "update" and "set" on sibling paths in relation to running a transaction?

Comment: update() and set() will behave similarly.  But to be clear, you can do a set on a *sibling* of a location you're doing a transaction() without issue, since it doesn't affect the data the transaction is acting on.  So doing a transaction on /foo/bar and setting /foo/baz is fine, but a transaction on /foo/bar and set on /foo or /foo/bar/foobar would cause the error.

Comment: Hmm... well that's a bit confusing. At no point am I doing a "set" on the "view_amount" path (see updated question). I might be doing a general "update" on the item itself, but I'm not updating "view_amount". Could it cause errors if I do an "update" on the item itself at the same time I'm doing a transaction on a child node of that item? It happens that a LOT of transaction are fired of at the same time for that particular item and path. Would that cause any issues?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.  I think there may actually be a bug that causes update() to trigger the error if you're doing the update at a parent location, even if it's only modifying siblings of the transaction location.  This is a bug, but for now you may need to work around it by using set()s instead of update() or else being careful not to do the update() while a transaction is outstanding. Sorry!

Comment: Hmm ok. So it's a bug in Firebase that you guys are working on? Can I track the bug somewhere, so I'll get notified when it's fixed? In my case, that makes "transaction" pretty useless.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen What do you guys say? Anywhere I can can follow the bug, so I know when I can implement transaction the correct way?